# Automatically expand range of Excel array formula (without macro)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

## Problem

How can I automatically add rows to an array formula as I manually add rows to a table? Similar functionality seems to be offered by Google Docs at https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?rd=1, and is adapted for Excel with a macro at http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=10&threadid=62734. However, using this macro requires enabling Microsoft Scripting Runtime, which I'd rather not do, and would also be difficult for the end-user to maintain. I'm running Excel 2013.

I am creating this worksheet for an end-user who may not be knowledgeable about VBA or array formulas, but will need to add items to a *Validation* table (described below). As the user adds table rows, my data validation range and its array formula are not automatically increased in length, and it's probable that the data validation will no longer show all acceptable values.

## Setup for Filtered Data Validation

You can view my stripped-down worksheet with macros disabled [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/0B_m4o9dWp5laQ1d3cTF3cm5WM3c/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104930188728087854490&resourcekey=0-d0GQCgNZu8qOLd3h63pP5A&rtpof=true&sd=true). Data validation on the Process column in the *Main* table will only show values that are currently showing in the Testing Process column in the *Validation* table. Slicers are included for ease of filtering.

Using help from http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html and some other sources, I have created a table named *Main_HIGHLIGHT* with data validation that only allows the visible/filtered values of a column in a second table named *Validation*.

The second table has three relevant columns, *Visible*, *Category*, and *Testing Process*. The table is filtered with a slicer on the *Category* column and the data validation returns values from the *Testing Process* column. A three-step process is used to prevent filtered values from appearing in the data validation:

1. Cells in the *Visible* column shows a blank if the table row is filtered out, and show the value of *Testing Process* if it's not filtered out. Its formula is:
   `=IF(AGGREGATE(3, 5,[@[Testing Process]])>0,[@[Testing Process]],"")`
2. An array formula directly to the left of the table, but not a part of the table, takes the range from *Visible* and sorts it so that all the blank cells are at the bottom of the range, and all the cells with a value are at the top. It fills a range with width 1 and height equal to the number of entries in the table. This range is given the Defined Name *Visible_Tests_with_filtered_removed*. The formula, entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter as usual, is:

   ```
    =INDEX(Validation[Visible],
            SMALL(
                IF( Validation[Visible]<>"",
                        ROW(INDIRECT("$A$1:$A$"&COUNTA(Validation[Category]))),
                        ""
                ),
                ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(Validation[Category])))
            )
    )
   ```
3. A Defined Name, *Visible_Tests_with_blanks_removed*, is created that includes only the values from *Visible_Tests_with_filtered_removed*, not any blanks or errors. Its formula is:  `=OFFSET(PPRNT!$A$34,0,0,MATCH("*",Visible_Tests_with_filtered_removed,-1),1)`

## Potential Solutions

Ideally I'd like to add the array formula to the *Validation* table, since that would automatically copy the array formula to any new row as it was added. When I try doing this, however, I get the error that "Multi-cell array formulas are not allowed in tables."

Alternatively, perhaps I could put this entire range into another Defined Name like *Visible_Tests_with_blanks_removed*, whose values are not actually located in cells on the worksheet. I don't know

If all else fails, I could use the macro I linked above, but it seems to me it shouldn't be this hard and I would probably just include instructions for expanding the Array formula in the HowTo tab.

Comment: What you're looking for is a Dynamic Named Range.  [This link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830287) and [this link](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html#Dynamic) both show different ways to create them.

Comment: I am using Excel 2016, and am able to enter CSE equations into a Table. Nothing as complex as what you are looking at however.

Comment: @OldUgly I can enter single-cell CSE formulas into a table in Excel 2013, but not **Multi-cell** array formulas, as noted in the error message. However, you jogged my thinking and I got a single-cell CSE formula that does work in tables. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @OldUgly for a bump in the right direction.

Download the example workbook from OneDrive at https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ak4Lq2gGjO8hleIyd60JuPkctlDhGw, but note the online preview doesn't support Data Validation! You must **download the file** to see it in action.

This three-step process creates the proper list for data validation, and it's part of the table so it updates automatically. Note that the CSE formula I used in my original question was multi-cell (select a bunch of cells, then enter the formula and hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter), but those aren't allowed in tables so this solution uses a single-cell array formula, which is automatically copied to every cell in the column in the table.

1. Create a *Visible* column on the table to determine which rows are currently hidden. This is a normal formula, not a CSE formula.
   `=IF(AGGREGATE(3, 5,[@[Testing Process]])>0,TRUE,FALSE)`
2. Add a *Filtered List* column to the table, and enter this single-cell CSE formula (which should get automatically copied to the rest of the cells in the table, just like any other table formula). If you press Enter instead of Ctrl-Shift-Enter, you'll get the #NUM! error for all but the first cell.

   ```
            =INDEX([Testing Process],
            SMALL(
                IF([Visible], ROW([Testing Process])-ROW(Validation[[#Headers],[Testing Process]]), ""),
                ROW([@[Testing Process]])-ROW(Validation[[#Headers],[Testing Process]])
            )
    )
   ```
3. Create a Defined Name *Testing_Processes_for_Data_Validation* (Formulas->Define Name) with the formula `=OFFSET(Validation[[#Headers],[Filtered List]], 1, 0, MATCH("*",Validation[Filtered List],-1), 1)` so that the Data Validation doesn't have a bunch of #NUM! errors at the end of it.

   When activating Data Validation on a cell, set Allow to be "List" and Source to be `=Testing_Processes_for_Data_Validation`.

And that's it! This creates an automatically-expanding dynamic list based on the filtered column of a table, and removes blanks and errors from that list.

Comment: Could you please share you file with formulas applied in accepted answer?

Comment: Here you go! The online preview doesn't support Data Validation, so you'll have to download the file to see it in action. https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ak4Lq2gGjO8hleIyd60JuPkctlDhGw

Comment: Thank you. Although you made it tidy and easy to follow, the overall solution to this simple problem is crazy complex.